# JTA Transactions Rollback of Routes using Directs?

Tags: transactions, apache-camel, jta

I have an interesting use case I was wondering if anyone had ideas on.

Essentially there is a notifications table in a database that has essentially the following structure:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "notifications";
CREATE TABLE "notifications" (
  "process_id" INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "table_name" VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  "last_updated" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  "last_processed" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("process_id")
);

INSERT INTO notifications (process_id, table_name, last_updated, last_processed) VALUES
(1, 'CASES_A', '2013-10-23 08:01:15+00:00','2013-10-22 08:30:22+00:00'),
(2, 'CASES_B', '2013-10-23 08:05:15+00:00','2013-10-22 08:05:15+00:00');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "CASES_A";
CREATE TABLE "CASES_A" (
  "case_id" VARCHAR(25),
  "case_date" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("case_id")
);

INSERT into CASES_A (case_id, case_date) VALUES
('5000NQLj451NJ1', '2013-10-22 18:33:25+00:00'),
('5000NQLj4992F1', '2013-11-05 17:19:02+00:00'),
('5000NQLj8N9J11', '2013-11-06 08:03:08+00:00');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "CASES_B";
CREATE TABLE "CASES_B" (
  "case_id" VARCHAR(25),
  "case_date" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("case_id")
);

INSERT into CASES_B (case_id, case_date) VALUES
('5000NQLk451NX4', '2013-10-21 10:23:26+00:00'),
('5000NQLk451NX5', '2013-10-20 11:10:25+00:00');
```

The idea is that we invoke a check of the notifications table (in production done with quartz) and then when there is a record that has a last updated date greater than last processed date, we read the data in table_name and process the records, routing them to the appropriate queue and when we have all the records routed, we update the last_processed date.

The use case has the following goals:

1. If a single record in table_name fails to process, it gets sent to dead letter queue but no rollback.
2. If a record is sent to the routing queue but an exception is thrown before the sub route is done, the record should be removed from the routing queue and sent to dead.
3. If there is an error in the update of the last processed time, all processed records are removed from the queues they are routed to.
4. If any record in table_name fails to get the direct, all records in that event should be aborted and last_processed not updated.

To try to implement this transaction strategy I have the following route and test case (note I have abbreviated items not relevant to the question.

```
package com.ea.wwce.camel.test.utilities;

import com.ea.wwce.camel.utilities.data.Record;
import com.ea.wwce.camel.utilities.data.RecordList;
import com.ea.wwce.camel.utilities.expressions.JodaDateTimeNow;
import com.ea.wwce.camel.utilities.jackson.RecordSerialization;
import com.ea.wwce.camel.utilities.transactions.TxnHelper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlConstants;
import org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static com.ea.wwce.camel.test.utilities.TransactionTestTools.*;
import static com.ea.wwce.camel.utilities.activemq.ActiveMQHelper.endpointAMQ;
import static com.ea.wwce.camel.utilities.jackson.RecordSerialization.toListOfJsonStrings;
import static org.apache.camel.ExchangePattern.InOnly;

/** Test Composite Transactions. */
public class CompositeTransactionTest extends AMQRouteTestSupport {
  public static final String MOCK_NOTIFICATION_END = "mock:notification_end";
  public static final String MOCK_AFTER_NOTIFICATION_SPLIT = "mock:after_notification_split";
  public static final String MOCK_CASE_SPLIT_END = "mock:case_split_end";
  public static final String MOCK_BEFORE_CASE_END = "mock:before_case_end";
  public static final String MOCK_ROUTED = "mock:routed";
  public static final String MOCK_AFTER_CASE_END = "mock:after_case_end";

  public static final String QUEUE_DEAD = endpointAMQ("dead");
  public static final String QUEUE_ROUTING = endpointAMQ("routing");
  public static final String QUEUE_TRIGGER = endpointAMQ("trigger");
  public static final String DIRECT_DO_CASE = "direct:do_case";
  public static final String DIRECT_DO_NOTIFICATION = "direct:do_notification";

  /** The database support object. */
  private H2DatabaseSupport dbSupport = createDBSupport(DBOnlyTransactionTest.class.getSimpleName());

  /** Jackson data format. */
  private JacksonDataFormat df = new JacksonDataFormat(createMapper(), Record.class);

  /** Jackson Mapper. */
  private ObjectMapper mapper = createMapper();

  /** Mock Endpoints. */
  private MockEndpoint mockDead, mockBeforeCaseEnd, mockAfterNotificationSplit, mockNotificationEnd, mockCaseSplitEnd, mockRouted, mockAfterCaseEnd;

  /** Creates a jackson mapper. */
  private static ObjectMapper createMapper() {
    final JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    factory.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS);
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
    mapper.registerModule(RecordSerialization.createJacksonModule(Record.class, null));
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
    return mapper;
  }

  public void initMocks() {
    mockDead = assertAndGetMockEndpoint(MOCK_DEAD);
    mockRouted = assertAndGetMockEndpoint(MOCK_ROUTED);
    mockBeforeCaseEnd = assertAndGetMockEndpoint(MOCK_BEFORE_CASE_END);
    mockAfterCaseEnd =  assertAndGetMockEndpoint(MOCK_AFTER_CASE_END);
    mockAfterNotificationSplit = assertAndGetMockEndpoint(MOCK_AFTER_NOTIFICATION_SPLIT);
    mockNotificationEnd = assertAndGetMockEndpoint(MOCK_NOTIFICATION_END);
    mockCaseSplitEnd = assertAndGetMockEndpoint(MOCK_CASE_SPLIT_END);
  }

  @Override
  protected void afterRegistryCreation(final JndiRegistry registry) throws Exception {
    dbSupport.registerNewDatasource(registry, DS_JNDI_KEY);
  }

  @Override
  protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    System.out.println("createRouteBuilder");
    return new RouteBuilder(this.context) {
      @Override
      public void configure() {
        context.setTracing(true);
        from(DIRECT_START).to(QUEUE_TRIGGER);
        from(QUEUE_TRIGGER).routeId(ROUTE_ID_TEST_ROUTE)
            .onException(RuntimeException.class).handled(true).useOriginalMessage().marshal(df).to(QUEUE_DEAD).markRollbackOnly().end()
            .transacted(TxnHelper.KEY_TXNPOLICY_REQUIRED)
            .setHeader(SqlConstants.SQL_QUERY, simple(SQL_CHECK))
            .to("sql:?dataSource=" + DS_JNDI_KEY)
            .convertBodyTo(RecordList.class)
            .split(body()) // Split checks
            .to(DIRECT_DO_NOTIFICATION)
            .end(); // end spit of checks;

        from(DIRECT_DO_NOTIFICATION)
            .onException(RuntimeException.class).handled(true).useOriginalMessage().marshal(df).to(QUEUE_DEAD).markRollbackOnly().end()
            .transacted(TxnHelper.KEY_TXNPOLICY_REQUIRED)
            .to(MOCK_AFTER_NOTIFICATION_SPLIT)
            .setHeader(HDR_PROC, simple("${body[process_id]}"))
            .setHeader(HDR_NOW, new JodaDateTimeNow("GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+00:00"))
            .setHeader(HDR_TABLE, simple("${body[table_name]}"))
            .setHeader(SqlConstants.SQL_QUERY, simple(SQL_CASES))
            .to("sql:?dataSource=" + DS_JNDI_KEY)
            .convertBodyTo(RecordList.class)
            .split(body()) // split cases
            .to(DIRECT_DO_CASE)
            .end() // end split of process cases
            .to(MOCK_CASE_SPLIT_END)
            .setHeader(SqlConstants.SQL_QUERY, simple(SQL_UPDATE))
            .to("sql:?dataSource=" + DS_JNDI_KEY)
            .to(MOCK_NOTIFICATION_END);

        from(DIRECT_DO_CASE)
            .onException(RuntimeException.class).handled(true).useOriginalMessage().marshal(df).to(QUEUE_DEAD).end()
            .transacted(TxnHelper.KEY_TXNPOLICY_REQUIRED)
            .marshal(df)
            .to(MOCK_BEFORE_CASE_END)
            .to(QUEUE_ROUTING)
            .to(MOCK_AFTER_CASE_END);

        from(QUEUE_ROUTING).to(MOCK_ROUTED);
        from(QUEUE_DEAD).to(MOCK_DEAD);
      }
    };
  }

  @Test
  public void testSingleCaseFailIsIsolatedAfterEnqueue() throws Exception {
    try (final Connection connection = dbSupport.connectH2WithInitScripts()) {
      startCamelContext();
      initMocks();
      final RecordList notifications = notifications();
      final RecordList casesA = casesA();
      final RecordList casesB = casesB();

      mockAfterNotificationSplit.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder(notifications);
      //noinspection RedundantCast
      mockCaseSplitEnd.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder((Object) casesA, (Object) casesB);
      mockRouted.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder(toListOfJsonStrings(mapper, casesA.get(1), casesA.get(2), casesB.get(0), casesB.get(1)));
      mockBeforeCaseEnd.expectedMessageCount(5);
      mockAfterCaseEnd.whenExchangeReceived(1, EXCEPTION_PROCESSOR);
      //noinspection RedundantCast
      mockNotificationEnd.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder((Object) casesA, (Object) casesB);
      mockDead.expectedMessageCount(1);
      mockDead.expectedBodiesReceived(toListOfJsonStrings(mapper, casesA().get(0)));

      template.sendBody(DIRECT_START, ""); // trigger process

      mockBeforeCaseEnd.assertIsSatisfied();
      mockAfterNotificationSplit.assertIsSatisfied();
      mockDead.assertIsSatisfied();
      mockRouted.assertIsSatisfied();
      mockNotificationEnd.assertIsSatisfied();

      assertFalse(isProcessTimeUnchanged(connection, notifications().get(0)));
      assertFalse(isProcessTimeUnchanged(connection, notifications().get(1)));
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the test case testSingleCaseFailIsIsolatedAfterEnqueue is not working. The test fails to roll back the message enqueued and it seems the messages are routed already before transaction commit. Does anyone have any idea of how this could be solved? I have been putting in significant effort into this test case and I am wondering that AMQ seems to not be participating in the transaction yet a test case with only AMQ in it and not the database works properly.

Your input or ideas are much appreciated.

---

EDIT

Interestingly enough it seems that AMQ is not participating in the JTA transaction. I don't know why that is happening at this time. Here is the setup of the transaction manager:

```
final Properties txnSvcProps = new Properties();
txnSvcProps.setProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.service", "com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory");
txnSvcProps.setProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir", "./target/atomikos/");
txnSvcProps.setProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir", "./target/atomikos/");
txnSvcProps.setProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.console_log_level", "DEBUG");
txnSvcProps.setProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.tm_unique_name", this.txnManagerServiceName);
/* The Atomikos user transaction service. */
atomikosUserTxnService = new UserTransactionServiceImp(txnSvcProps);
atomikosUserTxnService.init();
this.atomikosTxMgr = new UserTransactionManager();
this.atomikosTxMgr.setStartupTransactionService(false); // already started above.
this.atomikosTxMgr.setForceShutdown(false);
try {
  this.atomikosTxMgr.init();
} catch (final SystemException ex) {
  throw new AssertionError("Error initializing JTA transaction manager", ex);
}
this.userTxn = new UserTransactionImp();
```

And here is the AMQ Setup:

```
final ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory amqcf = registry.lookupByNameAndType(amqCFJndiName, ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory.class);
final ActiveMQComponent amq = (ActiveMQComponent) context.getComponent("activemq");
amq.setConnectionFactory(amqcf);
// -- Set Transaction manager because we will be using transacted(); note that this will find the correct one on the host platform.
amq.setTransactionManager(txnMgr);
// -- If we are using a JMSTransactionManager instance we have to set the connection factory in the manager.
if (txnMgr instanceof JmsTransactionManager) ((JmsTransactionManager) txnMgr).setConnectionFactory(amqcf);
```

Comment: Just added new information.

Answer (score 0):

Trying swapping the order of transacted/onException in the processEvent route. There was a rule saying (Camel in Action §9.2.2):

> When using transacted() in the Java DSL, you must add it right after
>   from() to ensure that the route is properly configured to use
>   transactions.

Do you use a JTA transaction manager and does ActiveMQ participate to the transaction as well?

Comment: That doesn't have any effect actually. I have tried that.

Comment: What is `TxnHelper.KEY_TXNPOLICY_REQUIRED`? Which transactionmanager are you using? Can you enable transaction logging (`org.springframework.transaction` level to DEBUG)?

Comment: TxnHelper.KEY_TXNPOLICY_REQUIRED is just a string constant containing the JNDI name of the transaction policy which is registered. As for the log, I am prepping a non-proprietary example. I will edit shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.end()` to `onException()` clauses as specified [here](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html%5d).

Comment: Actually I did add those. I simply made a copy paste error. The actual route is bigger and has stuff in it that is proprietary. I will edit the code and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When using Atomikos you have to wrap your connection factory in their own bean. Adding code like this solves the problem:

```
@Override
protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
  final CamelContext camelContext = super.createCamelContext();
  if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("Registering AMQ connection factory using key: {}", CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI_NAME);
  // -- create a connection factory proxy for atomikos.
  final AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean acfb = new AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean();
  acfb.setUniqueResourceName("amq-embedded");
  acfb.setXaConnectionFactory(brokerSupport.amqcf);
  acfb.setMaxPoolSize(10);
  acfb.init();
  registry().bind(CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI_NAME, acfb);
  ActiveMQHelper.configureActiveMQ(camelContext, registry(), fetchPlatformTxnMgr());
  return camelContext;
}
```

This code wraps the connection factory in the atomikos bean and thus solves the problem now when routes look up the connection factory they get the bean and all is sorted.